# String Parsing and Comparison

Tags: java, arrays, string

I've Created a function that accepts two String objects. The method returns a character array that contains one element for each occurrence of an alphabetic character that appears in only of the two strings. Any non-alphabetic characters in either string are ignored.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(alphabetize("ABc","abC"));
}

static String alphabetize(String one, String two) {         
    String result = one + two;   
    String expression = "^[a-zA-Z]*$";
    CharSequence inputStr = result;
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(expression);
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(inputStr);
    if(matcher.matches()) {
         char[] chars = result.toCharArray();
         Set<Character> charSet = new LinkedHashSet<Character>();
         for (char c : chars) {
             charSet.add(c);
         }
         StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
         for (Character character : charSet) {
             sb.append(character);
         }
         return (sb.toString());     
    } else {
        return null;
    }     
}
```

First of all, how can I sort the array in the way that returned value becomes in alphabetic order, with all uppercase letters appearing before any lowercase letter? Besides, the case is relevant and must be taken into account. For example, if provided strings “aBA” and “abA” the function should return an array consisting of {‘B’,’b’} because there is no uppercase B in the second string and there is no lowercase ‘b’ in the first string.
Additionally, multiple occurrences are relevant and must be taken into account. For example, if provided strings “aba” and “ba”, the function should return an array consisting of {‘a’} because the character ‘a’ appears in the second string only once.

**Example:**

[image]

Can anyone guide me through solving the problem? my handful of experience in java doesn't carry me to the solution.

Comment: If the resulting array consisted of {'A','a','B','b'}, would you want it sorted that way or would you want {'A','B','a','b'}?

Comment: Please put effort into formatting your code - it's all over the place at the moment.

Comment: @JonSkeet I'm sorry Jon, Isn't it already formatted ?

Comment: @Zircon Yes exactly, I've updated the question, added a table of examples.

Comment: No, it's not. Look at the post - look at the body of the `alphabetize` method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    HashMap<Character, Integer> store = new HashMap<Character, Integer>();
    arrangeFrequency("ababaABABR", store);
    arrangeFrequency("ababp", store);

    Object[] output =store.keySet().toArray(); 
    Arrays.sort(output);
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(output));
}

private static void arrangeFrequency(String str, HashMap<Character, Integer> s1)
{
    int defaultVal = (s1.isEmpty()) ? 1: -1;
    for(int i=0; i<str.length();i++)
    {
        char c = str.charAt(i);
        if(Character.isLetter(c))
        {
            int val = s1.containsKey(c) ? (s1.get(c).intValue()+defaultVal) : 1;
            if(val>0)
                s1.put(c, val);
            else
                s1.remove(c);
        }
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: Warning: it has a bug. fix it before sending to production. 
Hint: Give input as `"aa"` and `"aaaa"`.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `Map<Character, Integer>` for the character counts of the first string. Then iterate over the characters of the second string and if you find it in the map decrease the count by 1. If the count reaches 0 remove the character from the map, if you don't find the character in the map collect it into a list (or set if you don't want duplicates). At the end collect all characters still left in the map into the list as well adding it as many times as the map value indicates. Finally sort the list according to your needs.

Example:

```
String s1 = "xyyzaBC";
String s2 = "zyxBcA";

Map<Character, Integer> charCounts = new HashMap<>();

//Collect chars in s1
for( char c: s1.toCharArray() ) {
  Integer count = charCounts.get(c);
  if( count == null ) {
    count = 0;
  }
  count++;
  charCounts.put( c, count );
}

//Check chars in s2
List<Character> nonMatchingChars = new LinkedList<>();
for( char c: s2.toCharArray() ) {
  Integer count = charCounts.get(c);

  if( count == null ) {
    //character not found
    nonMatchingChars.add(c);
  } else {
    count--;
    if( count <= 0 ) {
      //count reduced to 0, remove now
      charCounts.remove( c );
    } else {
      charCounts.put( c,  count );
    }
  }        
}

//Add chars still in the map
for( Map.Entry<Character, Integer> e : charCounts.entrySet() ) {
  for( int i = 0; i < e.getValue(); i++ ) {
    nonMatchingChars.add( e.getKey() );
  }
}

//Sort
Collections.sort( nonMatchingChars );

System.out.println( nonMatchingChars );
```

Output: `[A, C, a, c, y]`

Note that this is not meant to be a full solution but to get you started. You'll need to add handling of non-alpha characters at least.

Comment: Thank you very much